# Saving data cross platform for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I want to write a phone application for me and my girlfriend to use. However, I use an android and she has an iPhone. I decided it wouldn't be too difficult to code it twice, but is there a way to share data between both phones in the app? For example, if I were to add an item to the list on one end, would it show up on the other? What ways could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you aren't together all the time, and you may need to use the app while you are not together, you're gonna need some sort of server, and a websocket in both apps; maybe google's firebase is an option.

Assuming you are gonna use the app only when you are in the same network, you can create a server in the android device, and consume the services of this server in both apps. Or you can establish communication using bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Try fire chat with common data point for android and iOS. There is a good example on the site. You can use it, also it is coming with 5GB transaction bandwidth. In this example there is a real time database which is connected by multiple clients. When ever you do update at any end, there is an immediate message at other end. This is like group chat with you and your girlfriend with your own database. There is no single line of server side coding. Its entirely client side application only. Try to download example apk and check your requirement is fulfilled or not and you can download the example and tweak it.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for something different. Like using a SQLite database that both could access? Or maybe some other method.. I couldn't find much information on how the information from Android can be passed to iOS.

Comment: You are looking for communication medium like BT or WIFI or NFC lke that or other?

Comment: Hmm not necessarily through those means. I'm looking for options to choose from at the moment before I start. And since there isn't much information on whether or not this is possible, I wanted to see what my options were, or if it's possible.